# How to search multi keywork in linq query

Tags: entity-framework, search, linq-to-sql, lambda, full-text-search

i have this code in homepage

```
 CheckBox[] ch= new CheckBox[12];
              ch[0] = ChkContextA;
              ch[1]=  ChkContextB;
              ch[2]=  ChkContextC;
              ch[3]=  ChkContextD;
              ch[4]=  ChkContextE;
              ch[5]=  ChkContextF;
              ch[6]=  ChkContextG;
              ch[7]= ChkContextH;
              ch[8]= ChkContextI;
              ch[9]= ChkContextJ;
              ch[10]= ChkContextK;
              ch[11]=  ChiContextL;
              for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                  if (ch[i].Checked) search += ch[i].Text + " ";
              Response.Redirect("SearchEstate.aspx?content="+search);
```

and this code in SearchEstate

```
  var content = Request.QueryString["content"];
         RealEstateEntities db = new RealEstateEntities();

               var query = from O in db.Owners       
                join E in db.Estates on O.OwnerID equals E.OwnerID
                join P in db.Properties on E.PropertyID equals P.PropertyID
                where P.Facilities.Contains(content)

                select new
                {
                    regdate = E.RegisterDate,
                    region = E.Region,
                    Estype = E.EstateType,
                    Fac = P.Facilities,
                    deal = P.DealType,
                    price = P.TotalCost,
                    img = E.Picture,
                    addrss = O.Address,
                    area = P.Area,
                    tel = P.TellNum,
                    bed = P.RoomNum,
                    park = P.ParikingNum
                };
    Repeater2.DataSource = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.regdate);
    Repeater2.DataBind();
```

when user checked some checkbox "content" for example have this value:
SearchEstate.aspx?content=ContextB ContextE ContextJ

I Want search this values in Facility field in db

How can I do this? (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling your are looking for something along the lines of this query:

```
var content = Request.QueryString["content"];

string[] contentArray = content.Split(' ');

//...

var query = //...
            where P.Facilities.Any(f => contentArray.Contains(f.FacilityName))
            //...
```

(or instead of `FacilityName` some other property of `Facility`)

But I am not sure.